# What do the values of the 'network' field in the NsdServiceInfo class mean?

Tags: android, network-programming, iot

I am implementing NSD Scanner in my mobile app. I already managed to make it work properly, and now I am wondering, how much info I can get from instances of NsdServiceInfo. What's interests me the most, is field 'network'.

I received an integer '112'. I assumed, it is some sort of code, but I wasn't able to find any specification, that explained, what that integer represents. Or maybe it is simply an ID, that is automatically assigned? I don't know. I looked through [NsdServiceInfo class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/nsd/NsdServiceInfo#getNetwork()) , [this Android Developers training page](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd#discover) and I even read full [document about NSD from IETF](http://files.dns-sd.org/draft-cheshire-dnsext-dns-sd.txt)

Maybe you know more about this field.